# The geometry in thermal expansion

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics, temperature

When we heat a metallic beam, it expands and we observe that for small ranges of temperature the change in length is proportional to the original length and the change in temperature. I do understand how this works for a beam, but what about someother objects.

Consider an isotropic donut shaped object. Upon heating I would think that the hole of the donut would become smaller and smaller with increase in temperature due to the fact that thermal expansion occurs in all directions and it should reduce the size of the hole, but my textbook states that 'Every linear dimension changes linearly with temperature for a given body' This would imply that infact the the radius should increase with temperature.

This seems to contradict my understanding. I would also appreciate if anybody had any proof or explanation for the statement mentioned in my textbook.

Comment: Consider the inner rim of the donut: it's a circle. If the hole of the donut got smaller, the length of the rim (perimeter of the circle) would have to get smaller. But in thermal expansion its length would increase, not decrease.

Comment: @brainfreeze I do understand what you are saying but you are only considering the thermal expansion of the donut only along it's periphery and not normal to it. Is there any reason for this? From my understanding, thermal expansion occurs equally in all directions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uniform temperature change in a **unconstrained** isotropic and homogeneous solid medium implies a scaling of the object, whatever shape it has.

In a linear elastic medium, the constitutive equation links the strain tensor with stress tensor and temperature difference
$$\varepsilon\hspace{-3pt}\varepsilon = \mathbb{C} : \sigma \hspace{-4pt}\sigma + \alpha \Delta T \, \mathbb{I}$$
For unconstrained systems, stress is zero, and thus only the **hydrostatic** thermal expansion occurs,
$$\varepsilon\hspace{-3pt}\varepsilon = \alpha \Delta T \, \mathbb{I}$$

To make things more explicit, let's introduce a Cartesian frame and write the non zero components of the constitutive equation
$$\begin{aligned}
 \alpha \Delta T & = \varepsilon_{xx} = \partial_x u_x \\
 \alpha \Delta T & = \varepsilon_{yy} = \partial_y u_y \\
 \alpha \Delta T & = \varepsilon_{zz} = \partial_z u_z \\
\end{aligned}$$
having introduced the expression of the strain tensor as a function of the displacement field $\mathbf{u} = u_x \mathbf{\hat{x}} + u_y \mathbf{\hat{y}} + u_z \mathbf{\hat{z}}$.

It's easy to integrate these equations to get
$$\begin{aligned}
 u_x & = u_{x0} + \alpha T \, x \\
 u_y & = u_{y0} + \alpha T \, y \\
 u_z & = u_{z0} + \alpha T \, z \\
\end{aligned}$$
From the expression of the displacement field, you can easily realize that temperature increase of an unconstrained system induces a homogeneous isotropic expansion (scaling) of the system (whatever is its shape, since we never used that information), along with an arbitrary displacement offset.

Comment: Haha I haven't yet been introduced to the concept of tensors in mathematics, and I would appreciate a bit more elementary explanation, but I do think I understood the gist of it.

Comment: Just trust me, then. That was a proof. It's just scaling. If you want to have a visualize that transformation, open **paint** or **gimp** or whatever program that allows you to draw a donut shape. Then copy it and scale it, and eventually compare the inner circles

Answer (score 1):

Consider the inner rim of the donut shaped object: a ring with infinitesimal thickness $dr$. Let the initial radius of ring (and thus, radius of hole) be $r$ and the coefficient of thermal expansion of the object  be $\alpha$.

[image: Thermal expansion]
If the ring is "opened up" as shown, it'd form a rectangle with sides $2\pi r $ and $dr$. After thermal expansion, let the radius of the ring be $R$.
$$2\pi R=2\pi r(1+\alpha\Delta T)
\\R=r(1+\alpha\Delta T)$$
Clearly, $R > r$. This means that the hole got bigger after thermal expansion.

An intuitive way to think about isotropic thermal expansion is to think of it as increasing the size of an object in a drawing app. In fact, that is how I drew the figure of the object after expansion.

Edit: a simple proof of why this is accurate:

For isotropic expansion, the coefficient of thermal expansion would be same everywhere, regardless of the direction of expansion or the part of the object. Coefficient of (linear) thermal expansion is $\cfrac{\Delta l}{l\Delta T}$.

Consider any two lengths on the body (they don't necessarily need to be straight, you can also take a curve), $l_1$ and $l_2$.

$$ \cfrac{\Delta l_1}{l_1\Delta T}=\cfrac{\Delta l_2}{l_2\Delta T} 
\\ \cfrac{\Delta l_1}{l_1}+1=\cfrac{\Delta l_2}{l_2}+1
\\ \cfrac{L_1}{l_1}=\cfrac{L_2}{l_2} = x \ (say)
$$
Here $L_1$ and $L_2$ are the lengths after expansion. $x$ is the ratio of final length to initial length. It can be considered as the scaling factor for the object: since every length on the object scales uniformly, the entire object scales by $x$ and thus its geometry is preserved. This is the same as enlarging an image on a drawing app.

Comment: I think your argument of making a ring a beam is similar to that of the statement I mentioned in my post to that of the book. While you do apply it, I do not understand really why it must be correct. Also the other thing you mention is how upon heating the geometry remains same and similarity is observed. While I do think it would occur practically, I still have no clue on why it works. I would think it to be a consequence of the fact that the thermal expansion is same in all directions, but I cannot make a convincing argument. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: @Blank the length of the beam and the "length" (perimeter) of the ring are the same. Since the coefficient of expansion is same and independent of the direction of expansion, straightening a curve won't affect its change in length. I've edited my answer to include a proof that the object scales like an image.

Comment: @Blank the proof is below with math, if you want a "why"

Answer (score 0):

Your book is correct.  For an unconstrained body, the new shape is geometrically similar to the original shape, and every linear dimension increases on heating by the same percentage $(\alpha\Delta T\times 100)$.  On what basis would you think that the hole would get smaller?

Comment: I was thinking that there would be expansion along the normal of the periphery inwards as there is equal expansion in all directions.

Comment: How could the inner circumference of the donut not increase?

Comment: My thinking was that due to expansion in all directions there should be expansion inwards which would result in the hole becoming smaller, other people do point out that the circumference must increase, though I must say it is a bit confusing for why must the expansion have to be out wards.

Comment: Expansion equally in all directions means that material particles get further apart, irrespective oftheir initial relative orientation.  You can only specify one point that does. not move.  Everything moves relative  to that point (say, the ceneter of mass of the donut).